# How can I build this equation in latex

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write this equation in latex but couldn't accomplish it. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: can you give an example of what you have tried and what you are having issues with.

Comment: What seems to be the problem with the equation?

Comment: Please don't ask questions "please do this for me" (see your question history). Show, what you have done til now and describe excactly what's the problem.

Comment: This question will be closed as too localized. It can be reopened if you would modify it so that it shows a real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\[\frac1b\sum_{i=1}^b\biggl[0.632\times0.5+0.368\times1\biggr]=0.684.\]
\end{document}
```

I'd like to know where you had a problem, though...

Comment: I get an error when I execute the above code.

Comment: @Vutukuri That code works without error for me. Perhaps tell us what error message you got.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac{1}{b}\sum_{i=1}^b
  \left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{b}}
    0.632 \times 0.5 + 0.368 \times 1 
  \right] = 0.684
\]

\end{document}
```

The only problem is to determine the size of the brackets. From the sample it seems that in this case the size is given by the fraction before the summation. The solution is based on using `\vphantom`,

> which makes an invisible box whose height and depth are the same as those of the corresponding `\phantom`, but the width is zero (Knuth, TeX Book)

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions like this which are overtly not appropriate for our Q&A format -- http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/should-we-answer-really-bad-questions